# How fast should my SELECT query be running ? 0.25 sec seems really slow

Tags: mysql

Struggling with a certain Select query which seems to take an awful lot of time whenever the id of the records I am searching increases to values above 100k lines .

The query is really simple :

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `object_id` = '1' AND `object_processed` = '0' AND `object_processing` = '0' LIMIT 1

When I have fewer records it takes 0.01 seconds or so to execute this query , but after a certain threshold it seems it suddenly increases from what seems to be a fairly normal execution time to a rather slow time of 0.25sec !

That is very critical considering I am doing a loop with thousands of iterations of this query, so it's having a big impact in my application .

I have indexed all the columns in this query (object_id, object_processed, object_processing) but it doesn't seem to help .

Any MySQL settings in specific I should be looking for to fix this ?

Here is my mysql cfg (on a 64gb RAM server)

```
wait_timeout = 25000
interactive_timeout = 25000
symbolic-links=0
open_files_limit=12000
max_connections=5000
max_user_connections=10000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 34
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=20
thread_cache_size = 100
join_buffer_size = 4M
tmp_table_size = 256M
innodb_autoextend_increment=512
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
key_buffer_size = 64M
```

Would really appreciate some help with this !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query needs

```
INDEX(object_id, object_processed, object_processing)
```

(The order of the columns in that composite index does not matter.)

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` leads to getting a random row; is that OK?

The only tunable that is likely to matter is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and you have it set to a reasonable value.

`max_connections=5000` is unrealistically high.  Unless you have a good reason, lower it to 200.